# How to make my touchpad work like a tablet?

Tags: drivers, touchpad, tablet, 19.04

I installed Ubuntu on my laptop and so far everything is working great, all the drivers are working the same way as in Windows.

Unlike this [gentleman's "problem"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/890629/my-touchpad-works-like-a-touchscreen), for me, this is how I want it to work but I don't know how.

Running `xinput list-props 16` will get the touchpad info:

```
Device 'ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (148):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (150): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (303): 1
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (304): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (305):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (306):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (307):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (308):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (309):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (310):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (285):   1
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (286):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (311):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (312):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (289):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (290):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (291):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Click Methods Available (313): 1, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled (314):    1, 0
    libinput Click Method Enabled Default (315):    1, 0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (294):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (295):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (296): -0.094891
    libinput Accel Speed Default (297): 0.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (301): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (302): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (270): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (271):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (272):    0, 0
    Device Node (273):  "/dev/input/event10"
    Device Product ID (274):    2, 14
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (287):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (288):   1
```

FYI, Elantech Touchpad, at least in Windows is not supported by some custom programs like AbsoluteTouchEx to make it use Absolute positioning.

Seems like using evdev could solve this, but I think this is something the physical device just can't support.

Comment: Did you try `xinput set-mode [device name] ABSOLUTE` (kurja's answer to the question you linked to)?

Comment: It gives this: 

`X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  131 (XInputExtension)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  5 (X_SetDeviceMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  18
  Current serial number in output stream:  18`

Comment: Are you using Wayland or X?

Comment: I'm using X11...

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/q/239823/349837) doesn't help you? Seems [touchpads rarely report absolute positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470935/how-to-read-absolute-positions-of-tap-from-cirque-touchpad-in-linux#comment3666929_3470935), for [sure not](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=75322) using synaptics